# jQuery plugin from JavaScript pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my actual code:

```
$.fn.menuWidth = (function(){
  return {
    show: function(a){
      this.animate({
        width: 400
      });
    },
    hide: function(a){
      return "hide";
    }
  };
}());

$("#header").menuWidth.show();
```

But, i can't access the `$("#header")` from the show `object`. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: did you try to do $("#header").menuWidth().show();

Comment: plugins should not return methods , rather should return `this` which allows them to be chainable. Not hard to find lots of tutorials on jQuery plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to change the structure of your plugin definition to something like this

```
$.fn.menuWidth = function(options) {
  this.show = function() {
    this.animate({
      width: 400
    });
    return this; // <---- This will enable chaining
  };
  this.hide = function() {
    return "hide"; 
  };
  return this; // <--- returning this will make visible the hide and show methods.
};

console.log($("#header").menuWidth().show().hide());
```

Doing jQuery's show and hide is also possible but this might sound a bit like a hack.

```
$($("#header").menuWidth().show()).hide();
```

menuWidth plugin returns `this` which is the instance of the element. Wrapping it into a jQuery object will let us perform `.hide()` and `.show()`.

This will not be possible if `.hide()` of menuWidth is invoked because it does not return the element instance.

PS: This is a very very simple way to write a plugin. There are better and much more complex ways to write plugins.

```js
$.fn.menuWidth = function(options) {
  this.show = function() {
    this.animate({
      width: 400
    });
    return this;
  };
  this.hide = function() {
    return "hide";
  };
  return this;
};

console.log($("#header").menuWidth().show().hide());
```

```css
#header{
width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  This is a header
  </div>
```

Comment: There is possibility to occur any conflict with native jQuery .show() function?

Comment: @CaioKawasaki yes, approach shown would over write jQuery default `show` for that element

Comment: @CaioKawasaki: Yes, it would override the show and hide methods. However, it is still possible to achieve that. `.show` method of `menuWidth  ` returns the jquery instance of the element. Wrapping that with a jquery object will let you perform jQuery's show and hide. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Like @charlietfl said, the override will happen just for `$("#header")`. Right?

Comment: @CaioKawasaki: Yes, just along that chain. If you break the chain and wrap into a jquery object, you will be able to perform all jquery operations. I hope I made some sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to change your function signature to `menuWidth = function(action) {};` then pass 'show' or 'hide' to the `menuWidth()` call. See https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#minimizing-plugin-footprint for jQuery's example documentation for this.

```js
$.fn.menuWidth = function(action) {
  if (action == 'show') {
      this.animate({
        width: 400
      });
  }
  else if (action == 'hide') {
     alert('hide');
  }

  return this;
};

$("#header").menuWidth('show');
$("#header").menuWidth('hide');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">Testing</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer too, however I prefer the chaining method, I'm sorry, I will accept the another answer...

Comment: @CaioKawasaki No problem and I agree that the other answer is just as good as I upvoted it also.

Comment: this is actually a more common pattern used IMO ..passing params instead of chained methods within the plugin but normally would `return this` so other jQuery methods are still available